# Can't Update SQL on VBA Access - Getting a Mismatched Type Error on String

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need a SQL Update a Long Text (Memo) on a Table but it's giving me an Error 3464, but have confirmed that the text I'm updating the Remarks into are Long Text (Memo) and what I'm updating is a string

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIdst.png)

[Table Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEXgy.png)

`DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE aaTest1 SET aaTest1.test1Remarks = '" & CStr(Me.txtBox1) & "'WHERE ((aaTest1.testPrimK='" & CLng(PrimKNum) & "'));"`

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75B4H.png)

Comment: You have to add space before `WHERE` clause. like `"' WHERE ((aaTest1.testPrimK='" & CLng(PrimKNum) & "'));"` and remove single quote from `PrimKey` criteria. `"'WHERE ((aaTest1.testPrimK=" & CLng(PrimKNum)));"`

Answer (score 0):

As I comment, try below command-

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE aaTest1 SET aaTest1.test1Remarks = '" & CStr(Me.txtBox1) & "' WHERE aaTest1.testPrimK=" & CLng(Me.PrimKNum)
```

Hope you are aware about variable declaring. More precise and clearer code here.

```
Private Sub cmdRunSQL_Click()
Dim strRemarks As String
Dim lnPrimKNum As Long

    strRemarks = Me.txtBox1
    lnPrimKNum = Me.PrimKNum

    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE aaTest1 SET test1Remarks = '" & strRemarks & "' WHERE testPrimK=" & lnPrimKNum
End Sub
```

Comment: @butzyspbm Then please mark it as answered. Tick mark it.